# CircleCI: env variable depending on branch

Tags: configuration, circleci

Id like to set different value for environment variable in circle.yml depending on branch name.Is it possible?

What i have:

```
machine:
    environment:
         MYVAR:"VAL1"
```

What id like to have is to be able detect type of the branch (master or not) and assign respective value to the variable?

Comment: Hi. I've answered the question no as this isn't possible. Could you provide more context on the purpose of the variable? Perhaps there's an alternative solution we can find.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See: [Build Details](https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/environment-variables/#build-details)

> CIRCLE_BRANCH
>
> The name of the Git branch being tested, e.g. ‘master’, if the build is running for a branch.

so, you can use `CIRCLE_BRANCH` ENV for detect current branch. After, you can add some logic in code for use `MYVAR_xxx` or `MYVAR_yyy` according to `CIRCLE_BRANCH`.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible using CircleCI due to how shells and environment variables work in our system.

-Ricardo
Developer Evangelist, CircleCI